# How to run a function from system?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, sql-grant

So I have a function called doLogin, that receives two arguments, and I created a user called user_login.
I have granted user_login the following privileges:

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO user_login;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DoLogin TO user_login;
GRANT SELECT ON Utilizadores TO user_login; --do Login gets information from this table
```

But when connect using user_login and try to run the function, I receive the following error:

> Erro: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13: PLS-00201: identifier 'DOLOGIN' must be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Edit: I would like that only system and user_login have acess to this function

Comment: Maybe you need to call it with SCHEMA.DoLogin, or define a public synonym?

Comment: And how would I do this?

Comment: @Aleksej I've tried doing: `ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = user_login`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you defined your function `DoLogin` in your schema (say `yourSchema`) and you need to use it from within a different user, say `user_login`.

You may decide to call the function with

```
yourSchema.DoLogin
```

or create a public synonym, from within `yourSchema`, and then call the function without adding the schema name:

```
create public synonym DoLogin for DoLogin
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This indeed solved my problem, but could explain better what are synonyms, I've seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364818/when-should-database-synonyms-be-used but I'm not really understanding

Comment: And by the way the synonym created is acessible to all users (if so, that's not what I wanted)

Comment: If you create a public synonym, it will be visible to every user, ma only users with the EXECUTE privilege will be able to run the function. In other words, you can think a public synonym as a way to avoid writing SCHEMA.object, but they give no grant

Comment: Or create a *private* synonym in `user_login` and make it reference `yourSchema.DoLogin`, so you can use it without schema alias from everywhere in `user_login` without exposing it to other users.